# Why memcpy is using void pointer as parameter?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

would it be OK if the function was: `void memcpy(char* dst, const char* src, size_t size)`?

What is the advantage of using void pointers in memcpy()?

Comment: Yes, you can. It is a void pointer as a notice that you can pass any kind of pointer to it. You don't HAVE to send a char*, or an int*, you can send a MyNewStruct* and it will copy memory just the same. But anyway, this is something that you can look up in literally 3 seconds. Pretty worthless question, I'm afraid.

Comment: `void *memcpy()` return destination... how would you get data with `void memcpy()' ?

Comment: @Krishna data is ready in *dst. Returning a pointer to dst is just a customary for chained function call, to me it is not mandatory though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the `void` data type was added in the 1989 standard, that *was* how functions like `memcpy` were designed.  `char *` was the closest thing to a "generic" pointer at the time.

The problem is that if `memcpy` still used `char *` arguments and you wanted to call `memcpy` on a target that wasn't an array of `char`, you would have to explicitly cast the pointer value:

```
int foo[N];
int bar[N];
...
memcpy( (char *) foo, (const char *) bar, N * sizeof *foo );
```

because you can't assign pointers of one type to another type without a cast.  This wasn't (as much of) a problem in pre-ANSI C because you didn't have function prototypes; that is, the compiler didn't check that the number and types of arguments in the function call matched the definition, but it's definitely an issue now.

However, unlike other object pointer types, you can assign any `T *` value to `void *` and back again without needing the cast, so the `memcpy` call can be written as

```
memcpy( foo, bar, N * sizeof *foo );
```

I remember the pre-standardization days (although I was still in college).  Casting gymnastics weren't fun.  Embrace the `void *` type, because it is saving you some heartburn.

Answer (score 2):

> would it be OK if the function was: void memcpy(char* dst, const char* src, size_t size)?

Yes, because pointers can be casted to another pointer type.

> What is the advantage of using void pointer in memcpy()?

Avoiding a cast to the destination pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the advantage of using `void` pointer in `memcpy()`?

A void pointer is a generic pointer, so it can accept a pointer to any type.

Comment: memcpy() does not "return" anything. You certainly meant "accept a pointer of any type" instead.

Comment: @Gil Yep, that's indeed what I meant to type. I'll fix that.

Comment: I plus'ed your answer, as it's more concise than mine now.

Comment: @Gil you said `memcpy() does not "return" anything`? I think it returns pointer to destination string.correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: Not in the syntax given by the question above: `void memcpy(char* dst, const char* src, size_t size)`

Comment: @Dayalrai `void` return type means it doesn't return anything of use.